# Why do I have to disconnect/reconnect my ethernet adapter?

Tags: network, usb, ethernet

I have a DongleBook Pro and I use a powered 7-port USB Hub. Connected to the Hub is a backup drive, an audio interface, an ethernet adapter, and some other stuff. The only device that causes me trouble is the ethernet adapter. For some reason, it won't actually give the computer internet unless I wake up the computer, unplug the adapter, then plug it back in.

When it's in the plugged in but no internet state I see the following in System Information, Network Utility, and System Preferences.[image]

Like I said before, the only way to get it to work is to unplug and plug it back in. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it not so that Internet goes off when computer is in sleep mode